# Laravel Spatie/Media with Voyager admin panel

Tags: laravel, voyager, laravel-medialibrary

I have the problem to make friends Spatie medialibrary with Voyager.
When adding Bread to this table, there is a field called Model Name. If I fill it with model that implements HasMedia, the Bread has created successfully. But when browse 'media' table - this table is empty. If i fill field Model Name with any anothor value, there is error - such class doesnt exist.

Table does have fields, I can see it with php-my-admin

**Update:**
I have added to my model code as it described in documentation https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/basic-usage/preparing-your-model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\Interfaces\HasMedia;

class Game extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    ...
}
```

adjust my model controller, so i can add image

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $newGame = new Game;

    $newGame->name = $request->game_name;
    $newGame->addMediaFromRequest('game_shortcut')->toMediaCollection('shortcut'); // изображение   
    $newGame->save();

    ...
}
```

Now I have uploaded image-file in my filesystem, and image entry in spatie 'media' table related to Game object.
http://joxi.ru/Vrwn5pbCKyWJgA

The problem is that I cant view 'media' table in Voyager, because I can not create BREAD properly

**Update:** if create BREAD without filling Model field, then it fails with

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ AccessDeniedHttpException
This action is unauthorized
```

error when browsing the table

Comment: Please add some code and the actual error messages. It's quite hard to help you with the information provided at this point

Comment: @Stormhammer, sorry. Updated for clarity